# C# socket message decompression

Tags: c#, sockets, dll, byte

i am new to the C# world. I am using it for fast deployment of a solution to capture a live feed which comes in this form (curly brackets for clarity): {abcde}{CompressedMessage}, where {abcde} constitutes 5 characters indicating the length of the compressed message. The CompressedMessage is compressed using XCeedZip.dll, and needs to be uncompressed using the dll's uncompress method. The uncompress method returns an integer value indicating success or failure (of various sorts, eg no license failure, uncompression failure etc). I am receiving failure 1003 http://doc.xceedsoft.com/products/XceedZip/ for reference of the return values from the uncompress method.

```
while(true){    
byte[] receiveByte = new byte[1000];
sock.Receive(receiveByte);
string strData =System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveByte,0,receiveByte.Length);
string cMesLen = strData.Substring(0,5); // length of compressed message;
string compressedMessageStr = strData.Substring(5,strData.Length-5);
byte[] compressedBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(compressedMessageStr);
//instantiating xceedcompression object     
XceedZipLib.XceedCompression obXCC = new XceedZipLib.XceedCompression();
obXCC.License("blah");
// uncompress method reference http://doc.xceedsoft.com/products/XceedZip/
// visual studio displays Uncompress method signature as Uncompress(ref object vaSource, out object vaUncompressed, bool bEndOfData)
object oDest;
object oSource = (object)compressedBytes;
int status = (int) obXCC.Uncompress(ref oSource, out oDest, true);
Console.WriteLine(status); /// prints 1003 http://doc.xceedsoft.com/products/XceedZip/
}
```

So basically my question boils down to invocation of the uncompress method and correct way of passing the parameters. I am in unfamiliar territory in the .net world, so i won't be surprised if the question is really simplistic.

Thanks for replies ..

##################################### updates

I am now doing the following:

```
int iter = 1;
int bufSize = 1024;
byte[] receiveByte = new byte[bufSize];
while (true){
  sock.Receive(receiveByte);
  //fetch compressed message length;
  int cMesLen = Convert.ToInt32(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveByte,0,5));
  byte[] cMessageByte = new byte[cMesLen];
  if (i==1){
    if (cMesLen < bufSize){
      for (int i = 5; i < 5+cMesLen; ++i){
        cMessageByte[i-5] = b[i];
      }
    }
  }
  XceedZipLib.XceedCompression obXCC = new XceedZipLib.XceedCompression();
  obXCC.License("blah");
  object oDest;
  object oSource = (object) cMessageByte;
  int status = (int) obXCC.Uncompress(ref oSource, out oDest, true);
  if (iter==1){
    byte[] testByte = objectToByteArray(oDest);
    Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(testByte,0,testByte.Length));
  }      
}

private byte[] objectToByteArray(Object obj){
  if (obj==null){
    return null;
  }
  BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
  bf.Serialize(ms,obj);
  return ms.ToArray();
}
```

Problem is the testByte writeline command prints out gibberish. Any suggestions on how to move forward on this ? the status variable of uncompress is good and equal to 0 now.

Comment: Get the error info and let us know what it says.[Find the error info](http://doc.xceedsoft.com/products/XceedZip/GetErrorDescription_method.html)

Comment: http://doc.xceedsoft.com/products/XceedZip/ --> click on 1003 for description.  


If you are uncompressing data, the data may be corrupted, or it has been altered in some way from the time that it was obtained by the Compress method. Verify that the compressed data you are getting from the Compress method is exactly the same as the compressed data you are passing to the Uncompress method (bit for bit).

If you are compressing data, this should not happen (but is a possibility). Contact Xceed Software if it does. You may be passing an invalid type data type to the Compress method.

Comment: read until `cMesLen` equals `compressedbytes`.
You are not reading the compressed message completely thats the problem!

Comment: @Anirudha re your comment above: yes, and treating arbitrary byte[] data as ASCII, converting it to string and back is **not** safe; that is, as I mentioned, very likely to trash the contents (in addition to the framing issue)

Comment: Re your edit: do you think maybe you should have copied some data into `cMessageByte` ? Also: you're **still** not checking how much data you receieved, or that you have a full message. I don't think you're appreciating how the packets can be combined, split, and buffered. How it is sent *is not* necessarily how it arrives. It is common to get partial messages, or multiple messages in a single chunk.

Comment: In other news; `BinaryFormatter` is also problematic; it isn't exactly frugal, and has *huge* problems with versioning. If only other serializers existed that were less verbose and didn't have these problems! (cough, cough)

Comment: does it not suffice that my return status is 0 ? after that should i not just be able to back out the message the uncompressed bytes represent ?

Comment: @MarcGravell forgot to paste that part of the code .. it's added now

Answer (score 3):

The first mistake, always, is not looking at the return value of `Receive`; you have no idea how much data you just read, nor whether it constitutes an entire message.

It seems likely to me that you have corrupted the message payload by treating the entire data as ASCII. Rather than doing a `GetString` on the entire buffer, you should use `GetString` **specifying only to use 5 bytes**.

Correct process:

- keep calling `Receive` (buffering the data, or increasing the offset and decreasing the count) until you have at least 5 bytes
- process these 5 bytes to get the payload length
- keep calling `Receive` (buffering the data, or increasing the offset and decreasing the count) until you have at least the payload length
- process the payload without ever converting to/from ASCII

Comment: Thanks Marc. Do you mean i keep exception checking for the size of the message ? and adjust the size of my receiving byte array ?  I run into the problem of the message size exceeding my buffer at 5 bytes

Comment: @AdityaSihag you don't necessarily need to resize the buffer, especially for messages that fit in in; just tell `Receive` how much (maximum) data you want.

Comment: @AdityaSihag correction: if you need to pass **just** a byte[] to the library, then yes: it'll need to be the right size